# Problema en la creación de un plugin al moverme de un archivo php a otro en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

Estoy creando  un plugin de wordpress en php.
Mi Index añade el plugin al menú y luego lo dirige a operaciones.php:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu','crearpagina');
function crearpagina() {
    $ruta = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__). 'operaciones.php';
    add_menu_page('UpdateStock','updateStock','manage_options',$ruta);
}
```

En  operaciones.php después de hacer varias  operaciones y mostrar varias cosas en pantalla aparece un un formulario(url: https://localhost/aplicacion/wpadmin/admin.php?page=updatestock/operaciones.php):

```
<form  action="../wp-content/plugins/updatestock/modificacionbase.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="producto" value="modificacion">
    <button type="submit" class="botones">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Al pulsar el botón me redirige de operaciones.php a modificacionbase.php me desaparece el entornos de wordpress y desde modificaciones no me deja acceder a las variables globales de wordpress(la url que aparece es : C:/xampp/htdocs/cazavip/wp-content/plugins/updatestock/modificacionbase.php).

Comment: es que te estas saliendo del ecosistema, el form dentro de un plugin debería apuntar a [`admin/admin-post.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)) y en el plugin definis un action que recibe valida y realiza una acción con los datos del formulario, o si es ajax la petición se hace a [`admin/admin-ajax.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) ambas url las conseguis en php con la función [`admin_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/admin_url/)

Comment: @aloMalbarez lo pones como respuesta?